# Create array based on instance of delimiter/square-brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, arrays, string

I have a string and I wanna create an array with even occurrence of "[]"

```
"Match[0][a][5][b][0][d][2]"
```

I want to split them and make an array using this string on the basis of instance of "[]". Each element of the array must have 2 occurrence of "[]" and the next element has two more occurrence of"[]". In another words I wanna create an array with even occurrence of "[]"

I want to make an array from string like:

```
["Match[0]['a']", "Match[0]['a'][5]['b']", "Match[0]['a'][5]['b'][0]['d']"]
```

Using javascript/jQuery

I have tried match but I only got it as far as this.

```
// ['part1.abc', 'part2.abc', 'part3.abc', 'part4']
'part1.abc.part2.abc.part3.abc.part4'.match(/[^.]+(\.[^.]+)?/g);
```

Comment: What is your expected output for one of your inputs?

Comment: ["Match[0]['a']", "Match[0]['a'][5]['b']", "Match[0]['a'][5]['b'][0]['d']"]

Comment: Not possible to get this directly from (JS) regex. You cannot get several matches from the same startinging position. You can build the result your self tho, which you could do with help of regex.

Comment: @Qtax I wanna do it with JS can we loop it and do this? could you show me a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the individual pieces in your array and then manipulate the result until it has the form you want. An example could be this one:

```
var str = "Match[0][a][5][b][0][d][2]";

var result = [];
str.split(/[\]\[]{1,2}/).slice(0,-1).reduce(function(acc,item, index) {        
  acc += '[' + (isNaN(item) ? "'" + item + "'" : item) + ']';
  if (index %2 === 0 && index !== 0) {
    result.push(acc);
  }
  return acc;
});

console.log(result) // ["Match[0]['a']", "Match[0]['a'][5]['b']", "Match[0]['a'][5]['b'][0]['d']"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get each bracket with `match(/\[.\]/g)` and then composes your arrays by adding two by two.

```
var matches = "Match[0][a][5][b][0][d][2]".match(/\[(.)\]/g);
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i += 2) {
    var brackets = '';
    for(var j = 0; j< i; j++) {
        brackets += matches[j];
    }
    result.push("Match" + brackets);
}
result.shift();
```

Comment: Is Match always the first word?

Comment: No it is dynamically generated

Comment: Will this always be in the form of some word followed by an even list of paired brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Wow its fun :) ... trying api and see how everyone is solving it. [This is what i tried](http://jsfiddle.net/anilnamde/92QJJ/1/) see if this is helpful.

```
str = "STR[1][3][4d][re]"

var re=/\[\w+\]/g;

var mat = str.match(re);
var ar = [];

for(i=2; i<= mat.length; i=i+2){
ar[ar.length] = "STR" + mat.slice(0,i).join("")
}
console.dir(ar)
```